# java.util.Objects#requireNonNull require api level 19 error

Tags: android

When I check the source code of [TokenReceiver](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin/blob/master/flutter-hms-push/android/src/main/java/com/huawei/hms/flutter/push/receiver/TokenReceiver.java), I found it use the requireNonNull under min api level 17. But after I move it in my code lab, it report the require min api level 19 error.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.Objects;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel;

public class TokenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final EventChannel.EventSink events;

    public TokenReceiver(EventChannel.EventSink events) {
        this.events = events;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction()).equals("flutter.intent.action.TOKEN")) {
            String err = intent.getStringExtra("TOKEN_ERROR");
            if (err == null) {
                String res = intent.getStringExtra("TOKEN");
                this.events.success(res);
            } else {
                this.events.error("-1", err, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Objects#requireNonNull(T) 
the Objects.requireNonNull does require API level 19.

Comment: The source of code show it use the min api level 17, so is just the error of source code?